# How to get the amount of color attachments using shader reflection in Metal?

Tags: ios, reflection, shader, fragment-shader, metal

I need to figure out the amount of MRT color outputs used in a fragment shader in Metal to setup the render pipeline accordingly in host code. However I couldn't find a way of doing it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I couldn't find a way of doing this. There is no API on `MTLFunction` for inspecting the return type, and even if you could get reflection information before pipeline creation time (you can't), it doesn't include return types either. What are you actually trying to do? Can you keep some metadata alongside your shaders that stores the number and formats of the expected attachments?

Comment: @warrenm: yes it's kind of weird that 1) the reflection API allows you to get MTLFunction parameter information, but not the return type, which is also important; and 2) that you can't get the reflected data before creating the actual pipeline. I needed this to setup the pipeline descriptor (the pixel formats of each color attachment) but I have to find a workaround to this. The metal reflection API is quite limited.